# Ubuntu UEFI Secure Boot - what if the MOK certificate expires

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

### Introduction

I've enabled a secure boot for my Ubuntu 20.04 as it was a mandatory step when installing a kernel module the (apt install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils). All went automatically and that's fine. The secure boot is working.

### Problem

But the generated key (the one used to "sing my boot") will expiry in a year.

### Question

Should I worry? Does it prevent my Ubuntu from booting after that date?